# If a function $f \in C^\infty[a,b]$ is 'a polynomial piecewise', is it actually a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was reading this [proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34067/108530) on MO of the following fact:

> Let $f$ be an infinitely differentiable function on $[0,1]$ and suppose that for each $x \in [0,1]$ there is an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$. Then, $f$ is a polynomial.

I understood the outline of the proof, except for one step: assuming that $f$ is not a polynomial, it is claimed in the answer that the set

$$
X = \{x \in [0,1] : \text{$f|_{(a,b)}$ is not a polynomial} \ (\forall (a,b) \text{ containing $x$}) \}
$$

is not empty. I have failed to understand why is that the case, so I am trying to see why $X = \emptyset$ would imply $f$ being a polynomial. I understand that by compactness of $[0,1]$, by assuming $X$ empty we would have intervals $I_1, \dots, I_n$ covering $[0,1]$ such that each restriction of $f$ is a polynomial, i.e. $f$ would be 'a polynomial piecewise'.

How can we conclude that $f$ itself is a polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if $f(x) = p_1(x)$ for $x \in (a,b)$ and $f(x) = p_2(x)$ for $x \in (c,d)$, where $(a,b) \cap (c,d) \ne \emptyset$, then $p_1 = p_2$.
You can see this by considering the Taylor series about a point in the intersection.

Comment: Okay, I think I see it now. Alternatively, one could state the equality of polynomials in the intersection and differentiating a sufficient amount of times, conclude that the independent coefficients coincide and afterwards proceed 'upwards' until proving that all coefficients are the same, right?

Comment: A more trivial way to argue would be that if two polynomials coincide at infinitely many points, they must agree (nonzero polynomials have finitely many zeros). Interesting to note that the overlap is key to this proof: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94038/is-f-a-polynomial-provided-that-it-is-partially-smooth?rq=1

Comment: @GuidoA. yes. gluing polynomials nontrivially (i.e. demanding equality on a neighborhood) is just extending a polynomial to a larger domain.

Comment: @RobertWolfe I was making this way more complicated than it need be, I don't know how I missed that! Interesting link, by the way. Thanks for the insight :)